# Can't pass json format key/value in command line for Spring Boot Console application

Tags: spring-boot

application.yml

```
username:  
password:
```

**Failed**:
1.java -Dspring.application.json='{"username":"XXXX","password":"XXXX"}' -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar

2.java -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar --spring.application.json='{"username":"XXXX","password":"XXXX"}'

The formats above didn't work. Why? What else should I add to the project?
[Official Docs.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

> The SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON properties can be supplied on the command
> line with an environment variable. For example, you could use the
> following line in a UN*X shell:
>
> $ SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"acme":{"name":"test"}}' java -jar
> myapp.jar In the preceding example, you end up with acme.name=test in
> the Spring Environment. You can also supply the JSON as
> spring.application.json in a System property, as shown in the
> following example:
>
> $ java -Dspring.application.json='{"name":"test"}' -jar myapp.jar You
> can also supply the JSON by using a command line argument, as shown in
> the following example:
>
> $ java -jar myapp.jar --spring.application.json='{"name":"test"}' You
> can also supply the JSON as a JNDI variable, as follows:
> java:comp/env/spring.application.json.

**Succeeded**:
1.java -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar --username=XXXX --password=XXXX

2.IntelliJ `IDEA Environment Variables`:
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON {"username":"XXXX","password":"XXXX"}

3.java -Dusername=XXXX -Dpassword=XXXX -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar

**Update:**
Checked @Sahit's correct answer. On the command line, the json string should be represented as string in java code. Starting and ending with double quotes, and escape double quotes in the string literal. [The docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) gives samples with wrong formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With -Dspring.application.json

```
java -Dspring.application.json="{\"username\":\"XXXX\",\"password\":\"XXXX\"}" -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar
```

With --spring.application.json

```
java -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar --spring.application.json="{\"username\":\"XXXX\",\"password\":\"XXXX\"}"
```

With SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON in WINDOWS

```
>set SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"username":"XXXX","password":"XXXX"}
>java -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar
```

With SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON in LINUX

```
>export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"username":"XXXX","password":"XXXX"}
>java -jar job-display-0.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the first form shown in the documentation...actually setting the env var?  The docs sure seem to suggest that what you're doing should work.

Comment: setting the env var? how to set env variable in code?